# jQuery selector in ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector

The script doesn't search the new selement (span) in the AJAX.

```
var str = $(this).html();
            var re = new RegExp(t);

            $(this).html(str.replace(re, '<span id="sel" style="color: red">' + t + '</span>'));

            if (t != "")
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: './ajax/translate.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: 'text=' + t,
                    success: function(response) {
                        $("#sel").html("!!!!!");
                    }
                });
            }
```

The text becomes red, but after AJAX, it doesn't turn into "!!!!!"...

How should i write selector for this span?

UPD:
i see that variable **t** becomes empty after refreshing the $(this).html(...) with the replacement...

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle with an example please?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that `t` is blank and that may be the reason why your ajax function is not getting called and eventually not appending '!!!!' to `str`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X9pky/